# How to access host network service during docker build process in docker for Windows

Tags: windows, docker, networking

#### Background

I have a Django application setup for development using docker and want to put the development environment in Windows, I am using Windows 11 pro with docker for windows installed, the docker services are up and running.

#### Problem

I am on the way to build the development environment from the below Dockerfile

```yaml
...
...

FROM ubuntu:20.04 as python_builder_seed
WORKDIR /workspace
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 LANG=C.UTF-8
# Install required packages for adding source list and keyserver
RUN apt update \
  && apt-get install -y \
  dirmngr \
  gnupg
RUN \
    echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa.list \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6A755776 \
    && apt update \
    && apt install -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    net-tools traceroute \
    iproute2 \
    iputils-ping \
    libffi-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    openssl \
    python3.6-distutils \
    python3.6-dev
RUN route -n
COPY Pipfile /workspace/Pipfile
RUN pip install pipenv==2020.11.15
RUN pipenv lock ==================> build failed here
RUN pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir logs
COPY . /workspace


FROM python_builder_seed as prod_python_builder
...
...
```

The build failed in `pipenv lock` with the following errors

```bash
...
...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
â ¹ Locking..âœ” Success! 
#25 38.77 Locking [packages] dependencies...
 Locking...Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
â § Locking..âœ˜ Locking Failed! 
#25 42.64 ERROR:pip.subprocessor:Command errored out with exit status 128:
#25 42.64  command: git clone -q https://repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com/phoenix/pydump /tmp/pipenv-3duqjlyo-src/pydump
#25 42.64      cwd: None
#25 42.64 Complete output (1 lines):
#25 42.64 fatal: unable to access 'https://repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com/phoenix/pydump': Failed to connect to repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com port 443: No route to host
#25 42.64 ----------------------------------------
...
<skipped>
...
--------------------
  73 |     COPY Pipfile /workspace/Pipfile
  74 |     RUN pip install pipenv==2020.11.15
  75 | >>> RUN pipenv lock
  76 |     RUN pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
  77 |     RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pipenv lock" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Following the message, I checkout the pipfile, and find out it should be the inability for the container to access the private repository URL (which is hosted in the internal network) since it returns "No route to host". Here are the contents of pipfile

```
[packages]
fabric = "~=2.0"
djangorestframework = "==3.12.2"
"psycopg2-binary" = "==2.8.6"
pyzmq = "==22.0.3"
"repoze.lru" = "==0.7"
cryptography = ">=3.4.6"
six = "~=1.15"
Django = "==3.1.7"
phoenix_protobuf = {git = "https://repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com/phoenix/phoenix_protobuf",ref = "v0.2.31"}
protobuf_custom_protocol = {git = "https://repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com/phoenix/protobuf_custom_protocol",ref = "0.13.11"}
channels = "==3.0.3"
channels-redis = "==3.2.0"
dump-phoenix-info = {git = "https://repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com/phoenix/py-dump-phoenix-info.git",ref = "v0.2.1"}
pydump = {git = "https://repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com/phoenix/pydump",ref = "v1.5"}
requests = "==2.25.1"
protobuf = "==3.15.6"
pyftpdlib = "==1.5.6"
pyreadline = "==2.1"
pyyaml = "==5.4.1"
```

The `repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com` is a self-hosted gitlab server (with IP 10.240.3.68) is connected in internal IP network 10.240.0.0/16, and my host windows machine (10.240.3.176) is also hooked up in this network, the host has no problem to access and clone the projects in this private repository.

#### Troubleshoot

So far I have done these things for troubleshooting

1. Add a sleep command to the end of the dockerfile, login to the container, and try to ping the gateway of the host network (10.240.0.1), I want to make sure the container can access the host network and in turn the private repository package, it did pingable.
2. I try to nslookup the `repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com/phoenix/pydump` inside the container to see if the IP can be resolved, and it can't, with the following errors

```bash
 > [python_builder_seed 16/24] RUN nslookup https://repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com:
#23 0.510 Server:               192.168.65.7
#23 0.510 Address:      192.168.65.7#53
#23 0.510
#23 0.510 ** server can't find https://repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com: NXDOMAIN
#23 0.510
```

And for the record, our DNS server should be 10.240.0.3 which is not 192.168.65.7 as shown, I then further run `route -n` and traceroute in the container,

route -n result

```bash
RUN route -n
#23 0.207 Kernel IP routing table
#23 0.207 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
#23 0.207 0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
#23 0.207 172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

traceroute result

```bash
#23 0.229 traceroute to repo.gitlab.dev.some.internal.host.repository.com (10.240.3.68), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
#23 0.229  1  172.17.0.1  0.167 ms  0.137 ms  0.127 ms
#23 3.379  2  10.1.0.1  3149.737 ms !H  3149.721 ms !H  3149.716 ms !H
#23 DONE 3.4s
```

So it clearly has some issues for the docker network to reach the host network from the clues here.

I then tried to add a route using route add and also try to add nameserver in resolv.conf during the build process, but none of them are allowed, being rejected with errors "Operation not permitted"...

So my question comes to

1. Is the in-accessible from the docker container to the host network by design?
2. If not, how can I make it accessible to the host network so that the private packages can be downloaded successfully?

Appreciate for any help